# Server Health Report in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have prepared server health report via PowerShell. My script is working fine but I am getting some random value in the bottom when I receive email via script, also I am not able to add body in my send-mailmessage command. When I do so script generates exception.
Here is my PS code:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Script for the detailed server health report

    .DESCRIPTION
    The script accepts parameter from CSV file by which we can get details and
    all information related to health status of the server.The script generates all the 
    information in a CSv file.

#>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]

    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Servercsv
    )
    begin{
        Write-Host "Running"
    }
    process{

         # Path for the CSV file that contains all the Print Server information.
        $ServerDetails=import-csv $Servercsv
        $result=@()
        $Outputreport = $null

         foreach($server in $ServerDetails){

         try{    

             #sysinfo variable contains complete systeminfo like manufacturer name, physical memory,servername 

             $cpu=Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $server.servers win32_processor| select __Server, @{name="CPUUtilization" ;expression ={“{0:N2}” -f (get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |
                select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average}}

             $disks =Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $server.servers -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" |
                Select-object @{Name = "PercentFree"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f  (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) } }


             $os=gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $server.servers |
                Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}

        $result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
            ServerName ="$($server.servers)" 
            CPUUtilization = $cpu.CPUUtilization.ToString()
            CDrive = $disks.PercentFree
            MemLoad = $OS.MemoryUsage

            }
            }

            catch{
         "error communicating with $($server.servers), skipping to next"
         }
         }

    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Utilization of Server Resources</TITLE>
                     <BODY background-color:peachpuff>
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""arial"">
                     <H3> Utilization of Server Resources</H3></font>
                     <Table border=2 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=5>
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center>
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>CPUUtilization</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>CDrive</B></TD></TR>"


    Foreach($Entry in $Result){

    if(([decimal]$Entry.CPUUtilization -ge 15) -or ([decimal]$Entry.MemLoad -ge 50) -or (([decimal]$Entry.CDrive) -le 60) )
    {
    $Outputreport += "<TR>"

     $Outputreport += "<TD><B>$($Entry.Servername)</B></TD>"
     if([decimal]$Entry.CPUUtilization -ge 15)
        {

        $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:red;>$($Entry.CPUUtilization+'%')</TD>"
        }
        else {
        $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:White;>$($Entry.CPUUtilization+'%')</TD>"
        }


        if([decimal]$Entry.MemLoad -ge 50)
        {

        $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:red;>$($Entry.MemLoad+'%')</TD>"
        }
        else{
         $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:White;>$($Entry.MemLoad+'%')</TD>"
         }



       if(([decimal]$Entry.CDrive) -le 60)
       { 

        $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:red;>$($Entry.Cdrive+'%')</TD>"
        }
        else{ $Outputreport += "<TD align=center style=color:White;>$($Entry.Cdrive+'%')</TD>"}


         #$Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD>"


         #$Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD>"

        $Outputreport+="</TR>"

           }



     }

     $Outputreport += "</Table><p>Hello</p></BODY></HTML>" 
      $out=$Outputreport | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Outputreport
     #Send an email about the Load

        # $smtp is the outgoing mail server 
        $smtp= "smtphost.redmond.corp.microsoft.com"

        try{
        send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $smtp -from v-rubhat@microsoft.com  -to v-rubhat@microsoft.com  -subject "Server Health Report"  -BodyAsHtml "$out" 
        }
        catch [exception]
        {
        write-host ("Cannot send mail, since argument is null or empty")
        }


    }
```

Below is my attached output and that * and 1121 is that random number:

Utilization of Server Resources
Server Name CPUUtilization  Memory Utilization  CDrive
xxxxxxxx    3.25%   29.26%  22.11%
xxxxxxxx    18.80%  52.15%  57.49%
xxxxxxxx    27.76%  27.51%  71.91%

*
1121

Comment: This `$out=$Outputreport | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Outputreport` makes no sense to me since `$Outputreport` already is a string containing HTML. For the Send-MailMessage cmdlet, you are missing parameter `-Body` as in `-Body $Outputreport`. Also, you should add `-ErrorAction Stop` there, so non-terminating errors will be cought in the `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the $out variable and added property attribute in it and that worked. Here's my edited $out command

```
$out=$Outputreport | ConvertTo-Html -Property Servername,CPUUtilization,MemLoad,CDrive -Head $Outputreport
```